# Reset datetimepicker to current month

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using datetimepicker function to select date and time in separate text boxes. Below is the code.

We want to reset the Requested Completion Date input textbox to the current month after clicking the reset button. Suppose I selected 23 September 2019, after clicking the reset button it should reset datetimepicker to the current month. But when you click again in textbox it opens datepicker with September month which is previously selected.

To do that I created function `resetMonth()`. But it is throwing following error in the function:

> $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

```html
<div>
  <b>Requested Completion Date: *</b><br />
  <input id="requestedCompletionDate" type="text" class="form-control" /><br />
  <b>Requested Completion Time: *</b><br />
  <input id="requestedCompletionTime" type="text" class="form-control" /><br />

  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="resetMonth()" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <script>
      $('#requestedCompletionTime').datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
      });
      $('#requestedCompletionDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
        useCurrent: false
      });

      function resetMonth() {
        $('#requestedCompletionDate').datetimepicker({
          format: 'MM-DD-YYYY',
          useCurrent: false
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: You're including the datetimepicker library twice. I'd suggest removing the non-min.js version. This shouldn't be causing your issue, though.

Comment: I removed `<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>` but still having same issue. I want to reset datetimepicker to the current month again.